# Can python sitk.ReadImage read a list/series of images?

Tags: python, itk, simpleitk

I do not understand if sitk.ReadImage can read a list of images or not? I did not manage to find an example showing how to list of images should be inputed to the function.
But in the function documentations it say:

```
ReadImage(**VectorString fileNames**, itk::simple::PixelIDValueEnum outputPixelType) -> Image
ReadImage(std::string const & filename, itk::simple::PixelIDValueEnum outputPixelType) -> Image



ReadImage is a procedural interface to the ImageSeriesReader class which is convenient for most image reading tasks.


Note that when reading a series of images that have meta-data
associated with them (e.g. a DICOM series) the resulting image will
have an empty meta-data dictionary. It is possible to programmatically
add a meta-data dictionary to the compounded image by reading in one
or more images from the series using the ImageFileReader class,
analyzing the meta-dictionary associated with each of those images and
creating one that is relevant for the compounded image.
```

So it seems from the documentations that it is possible. Can someone show me a simple example.

EDIT: 
I tried the following:

```
sitk.ReadImage(['volume00001.mhd','volume00002.mhd'])
```

but this is the error that I get:

```
RuntimeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-85abf82c3afa> in <module>()
      1 files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if 'mhd' in f]
      2 print(sorted_files[1:25])
----> 3 sitk.ReadImage(['volume00001.mhd','volume00002.mhd'])

/gpfs/bbp.cscs.ch/home/amsalem/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SimpleITK/SimpleITK.pyc in ReadImage(*args)
   8330 
   8331     """
-> 8332     return _SimpleITK.ReadImage(*args)
   8333 class HashImageFilter(ProcessObject):
   8334     """

RuntimeError: Exception thrown in SimpleITK ReadImage: /tmp/SimpleITK/Code/IO/src/sitkImageSeriesReader.cxx:145:
sitk::ERROR: The file in the series have unsupported 3 dimensions.
```

Thanks.

Comment: The error message seems self explainitory, reading a series of 3D images is not supported.  The common usage is to read a series of 2d image to form a 3d image. Please provide details about your images and what you are trying to do.

Comment: @blowekamp so my question is all wrong, I should have asked, if ReadImage can read a sequence of 3d images. The images are just raw binaries, the hmd is the details of the image. I think I might delete this question and maybe open a new one which has a better title and better information.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleITK uses SWIG to wrap a C++ interface to Insight Segmentation and Registration Toolkit (ITK). As such the inline python documentation should be supplemented with the C++ Doxygen documentation. There is a mapping of C++ types to Python types with robust implicit conversion between them. You can find the documentation for the sitk::ReadImage methods here:
 https://itk.org/SimpleITKDoxygen/html/namespaceitk_1_1simple.html#ae3b678b5b043c5a8c93aa616d5ee574c

Notice there are 2 ReadImage methods, and the Python docstring you listed appears is one of them.

From the SimpleITK examples here is a snippet to read a DICOM series:

```
print( "Reading Dicom directory:", sys.argv[1] )
reader = sitk.ImageSeriesReader()

dicom_names = reader.GetGDCMSeriesFileNames( sys.argv[1] )
reader.SetFileNames(dicom_names)

image = reader.Execute()
```

This uses the class interface as opposed to the procedural. Which would simply be:

```
image = sitk.ReadImage(dicom_names)
```

or generically with a list of string filenames:

```
image = sitk.ReadImage(["image1.png", "image2.png"...])
```

Many common array like type of strings will be implicitly converted to the SWIG `VectorString` type.

Comment: Thanks blowekamp, image = sitk.ReadImage(["image1.png", "image2.png"...]) does not work. look at the edit that I made.

Comment: I will also add to this, since the documentation doesn't mention it, that you have to specify as path the exact directory that directly contains the files. SimpleITK won't search for the files in the subdirectories, if you will specify upper-level directory. (I.e., as an argument to the reader.GetGDCMSeriesFileNames)